# How to get QColor::greenF color value exactly between 0 and 1 instead of rounding off?

Tags: c++, qt, rgb, qcolor

I have a `QColor` value and I need to break it down into its RGB components between 0 and 1 with only one value after decimal point.
For example: `Orange color` is

```
QColor color = QColor(255,128,0)
qreal green = color.greenF();
qDebug() << green; //0.501960784
```

Whereas the green component must be `0.6`. That is, it's `rgb value is (255,128,0) or (1,0.6,0).`

How to get `0.6` instead of `0.501960784`?

Comment: 128/255 is not 0.6. Have you tried using 153 instead?

Comment: @Angew But Orange color is `255,128,0` and '255,153,0' will be the different type of orange color. I have to map 0-255 range to 0-1 range to reflect the same color exactly.

Comment: `round(128/255)` is `0.5`

Comment: @xcfg96 
Where did you get that it should be 0.6?

Comment: @xcfg96 Well, the colour will either be `255, 128, 0` (which is pretty close to `(1, 0.5, 0)`), or it will be `1, 0.6, 0` (which is `255, 153, 0`). You cannot have both, they're different colours.

Comment: @eyllanesc Here https://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2007-4/walden/color.pdf page no. 11 first row, second color.

Comment: @xcfg96 OK, and what tells you that the colour on page 11 should have values `255, 128, 0`?

Comment: Do you understand what the floating and integral values of RGB mean? The floats are just the integers divided by 255.

Comment: @xcfg96  that will depend on the convention that is used, if you check on the internet you will find that the orange has different rgb values, for example in SVG it is: `orange rgb(255, 165, 0)` https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#ColorKeywords

Comment: @Angew So if I divide any 0-255 color by 255 to get the color in range 0-1, then will both the color in 0-255 and 0-1 range will be exactly same? Is it always guaranteed? If not, is there any way?

Comment: @xcfg96 the color orange and the other colors that have a name do not have an exact value, it will depend on the convention that is used, so there will not be a solution that fits in all, for example you are using a convention used by the author of that post made for your latex library, I do not think it is not a convention for all latex.

Comment: @xcfg96 Who tells you that the transformation is linear? If it is linear, it should coincide but it seems that it is not.

Comment: @eyllanesc Then is there any way to convert 0-255 Qt RGB color to 0-1 range while having the same color exactly? If there is a way, please make an answer. Please.

Comment: Why do you assume that `255,128,0` is that orange color in the PDF ?, I have used a Picker color and I have found that the color is: R: 254 G: 154 B: 52

Comment: @eyllanesc Ok I'm sorry I'm not assuming anything but can you tell me a way to transform the color from 0-255 range to 0-1 range?

Comment: Use `greenF()`,`redF()` and `blueF()`

Comment: @eyllanesc I used `rgb(139,69,19)` value for saddle brown for example and with `greenF() redF() blueF()`, I got a different reddish brown color. Why?

Comment: Where do you get the RGB values ​​?, also understand that the conversion to float is lost precision. How are you doing your test?

Comment: @eyllanesc `QColor color = QColor(139,69,19);
 qreal red = color.red(), green = color.green(), blue = color.blue();
 qDebug() << red <<" " << green <<" " << blue;
    GooString * s = GooString::format("{0:f} {1:f} {2:f} rg /Invalid_font {3:d} Tf", red, green, blue, font.pointSize());`

Comment: @eyllanesc I got color value and name from web and I'm developing a pdf application in which the user will choose the font QColor and the same will be rendered by pdf library. In the pdf library, it is GooString that takes `r g b rg` r g b operands and rg operator with operands value between 0 and 1. Hence I need to convert the color range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But Orange color is 255,128,0

There is no such thing as "the" orange color. Everyone calls something else using the same word. Orange isn't *a color*, it's a range of *hues*. Those hues become colors once you assign them some saturation and brightness. There's a whole lot of colors that can be represented using an 8-bit-per-componet R,G,B triple that all have a hue that is orange, and that thus qualify as *an* orange. There's no *the* orange,

> Whereas the green component must be 0.6. That is, it's rgb value is (255,128,0) or (1,0.6,0).

It's not. `QColor` tells you so, and basic math tells you so. The color **clearly** is `1/0.6/0`, or `1*255, 6/10*255, 0*255`, or `255, 1530/10, 0` or `255, 153, 0` **exactly**. It won't ever be `255,128,0` and I have no idea who told you that, but they were wrong.

So it's really simple: forget it all. Just use `QColor::redF`, `greenF` and `blueF`. They work the way they should.

Oh, and you didn't even mention the elephants in the room that are color spaces. An RGB triple has no physical meaning - it's entirely abstract - until you map it to a physical color space. And you better use calibrated output devices to interface your color choice with the user, otherwise it'll be endless silliness all around.